# Difference in flatMap(_) and flatMap(x => x)

Tags: scala, flatmap

While solving a collection exercise question from Scala for Impatient:

Write a function that receives a collection of strings and a map from strings to integers. Return a collection of integers that are values of the map corresponding to one of the strings in the collection. For example, given `< Array("Tom", "Fred", "Harry") >` and `< Map("Tom" -> 3, "Dick" -> 4, "Harry" -> 5) >` return `< Array(3,5) >`. Hint: use `<flatMap>` to combine the `<Option>` values returned by `<get>`.

Here is what my solution and works fine:

```
def mapValues(list: List[String], mapper: Map[String, Int]) : List[Int] = {
   list.map(mapper.get).flatMap(x => x)
}
```

However, changing the code to

```
list.map(mapper.get).flatMap(_)
```

I get an error for return type. It asks me to change the return type to ((Option[Int]) => GenTraversableOnce[_B]) => List[Nothing]

What is the difference between flatMap(x => x) and flatMap(_). To my understanding, both are the same.

P.S. The simpler solution to the problem is though

```
list.flatMap(mapper.get)
```

Comment: `flatMap(_)` just isn't valid Scala syntax, and in general you'll never use `flatMap` with the identity function—use `flatten`, or change a previous `map` to `flatMap` as you have here, if that's possible. There are cases where it's reasonable to pass the identity function to a method, but it's relatively rare, and having `_` be the identity function would make Scala's convoluted syntax even more of a mess.

Comment: To be a little pedantic, `flatMap(_)` is valid syntax, it just means something else: it means `x => flatMap(x)`

Comment: I think rather than using flatMap(_) u can use flatten as you are not modifying anything from the dataset